# How to compile code without having the needed library 'installed' in your system?

Tags: compiling, c++, libraries, sdl

In one of my projects in working with the [SDL 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) libraries. My computer went kaput last night and at my uni my profile doesn't have sudo powers.

Is there a way to compile and run my code without having to install the SDL library via the ol' `sudo apt-get install ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to install the libraries manually yourself. Download the zipfile from the link in your question, unzip it and follow the instructions. Usually, there is a `config` script included and you can tell it to set up the library so that it is installed in a directory you have access to. Normally, this is done like so:

```
./configure --prefix=~/lib
```

That will install in a directory called `lib` which is in your `$HOME`. You will then have to tell your compiler to include that directory when searching for libraries. Something like:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" g++ foo.c
```

Comment: And how do I do that? Telling g++ to include the new directory, I mean...

Comment: @FerndinandUrsa see updated answer. Not really sure about the details, I'm afraid, I don't do much compiling. This should at least send you in the right direction.